# Python Subprocess when using a variable in the parameters the variable's quotes show

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code.

```
scrcpy_subprocess = subprocess.Popen([scrcpy_executable, '--serial', device_selection['devices']], stdin=None, stdout=console_log, stderr=console_log)
```

this section

```
device_selection['devices']
```

when the program run. the variable stored in the variable above
still includes the quotes.

which means it's result is this..

```
error: failed to get feature set: device 'AQYHCE9L5LH6EMDY
' not found
```

anybody know a way to fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error it really looks more like you're including a newline in there, not the quotes.

Try

```
device = device_selection["devices"].strip()  # remove trailing/leading spaces
scrcpy_subprocess = subprocess.Popen(
    [scrcpy_executable, "--serial", device],
    stdin=None,
    stdout=console_log,
    stderr=console_log,
)
```

or if it really still doesn't work,

```
# remove trailing/leading spaces, then all quotes
device = device_selection["devices"].strip().replace("'", "")
```

Comment: thanks. this works.
after looking in the code. it seems like the process 'adb get-serialno' seems to give me the newlines.

Comment: Yes, command output tends to include a trailing newline. Please be sure to accept the answer if it helped you :)